# Next.JS _error page don't show correct error message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, error-handling, server-side-rendering

I was trying to catch the error message coming from the server side inside the _error page

```js
// page.tsx
export default function Page() {
  return <>Hello World</>
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
    throw new Error('Test error')
}
```

I expected that the _error.tsx page would display within the `<h1>` the message "Test error", but it is displaying "500 - Internal Server Error."

The page shows this:

---

## 500 - Internal Server Error.

An error 500 occurred on server

---

As the page loads, it displays "Test error", but when the loading completes, it shows "500 - Internal Server Error."

This is probably because getInitialProps runs on both the server-side and the client-side.

In the source code it displays "Test error"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/><meta name="next-head-count" content="2"/><noscript data-n-css=""></noscript><script defer="" nomodule="" src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills-c67a75d1b6f99dc8.js"></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack-4e7214a60fad8e88.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/framework-3b5a00d5d7e8d93b.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-6bd05e2d46af9dd4.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app-17bcdbe1cad2241d.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/chunks/pages/_error-4e68bbc6124036ee.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/77B-OjgsFyCHh5A8ds7Hs/_buildManifest.js" defer=""></script><script src="/_next/static/77B-OjgsFyCHh5A8ds7Hs/_ssgManifest.js" defer=""></script></head><body><div id="__next">
<h1>Test error</h1>
<p>An error 500 occurred on server</p></div>
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__" type="application/json">
{"props":{"pageProps":{"statusCode":500,"err":{}}},"page":"/_error","query":{"authuser":"2","redirectedPreviously":"true"},"buildId":"77B-OjgsFyCHh5A8ds7Hs","isFallback":false,"err":{"name":"Internal Server Error.","message":"500 - Internal Server Error.","statusCode":500},"gip":true,"scriptLoader":[]}
</script></body></html>
```

I tried this code:

```js
// _error.tsx
import { NextPage, NextPageContext } from 'next'

interface Props {
  statusCode?: number
  err: any
}

const Error: NextPage<Props> = ({ statusCode, err }) => {
  console.log(err) // {"name":"Internal Server Error.","message":"500 - Internal Server Error.","statusCode":500}
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{err.message}</h1>
      <p>
        {statusCode ? `An error ${statusCode} occurred on server` : 'An error occurred on client'}
      </p>
    </>
  )
}

Error.getInitialProps = ({ res, err }: NextPageContext) => {
  console.log(err?.message) // 500 - Internal Server Error. (client-side); Test error (server-side)
  const statusCode = res ? res.statusCode : err ? err.statusCode : 404
  return { statusCode, err }
}

export default Error
```

I also tried changing the property name "err" to something else and nothing worked